# Can severity be set conditionally for imfile input in rsyslog 8.32?

Tags: rsyslog

I have a text logfile from an application that is formatted like so...

```
2019-12-18 12:32:00 DEBUG This is a debugging line
2019-12-18 12:32:15 This is a informational line
2019-12-18 12:32:17 WARNING This is a warning line
2019-12-18 12:32:33 ERROR This is an error line
2019-12-18 12:33:44 ERROR This is a multi-line error message
    This is more of the previous error message
2019-12-18 12:34:15 This is back to another informational line
```

I have configured rsyslog to ingest this file using the imfile module and ship it off to my central syslog server...

```
module(load="imfile")

input(type="imfile"
      file="/usr/share/myapplication/myapplication.log"
      tag="myapplication-log:"
      facility="local4"
      severity="info"
      startmsg.regex="^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2} [0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} "
      readTimeout="5"
)

*.* @192.168.1.4
```

So far so good. The remote syslog server receives the lines correctly and handles the multi-line error as a single message. Almost perfect, but now I want to expand things a bit.

All syslog messages in the above are sent as local4.info as expected. The original message lines contain enough information for me to be able to correctly identify the proper 'severity' level for the message and I'd like to be able to do that, but I can't seem to figure out the method.

Something to the effect of this non-working pseudo-code...

```
if $programname == "myapplication-log" then {
    if ($msg contains " DEBUG ") then severity debug;
    if ($msg contains " WARNING ") then severity warn;
    if ($msg contains " ERROR ") then severity error;
}
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

-- EDIT for clarity --

As @meuh pointed out, this could be accomplished at the output phase using templating, but my preference would be to have the  severity correctly determined during the input phase. This way, any outputs of this message log are handled exactly the same as any other log and I don't have to remember to perform special output handling if my outputs change a year from now.

A better pseudo-code example of what I am looking for would be...

```
input(type="imfile"
      file="/usr/share/myapplication/myapplication.log"
      tag="myapplication-log:"
      facility="local4"
      severity="info"
      severity="debug" if ($msg contains " DEBUG ");
      severity="warn" if ($msg contains " WARNING ");
      severity="error" if ($msg contains " ERROR ");
      startmsg.regex="^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2} [0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2} "
      readTimeout="5"
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the input has been parsed, you enter a second phase where you have access to the properties and can create a template variation on the usual network output.  The `<prio>` part of the output is made up from

```
prio = facility*8 + severity
```

where rfc5424 lists the numbers for each facility and severity: `Local4` is 20, severity debug is 7, warning 4, error 3.

The standard `RSYSLOG_ForwardFormat` used to send messages is defined as

```
template(name="RSYSLOG_ForwardFormat" type="string"
 string="<%PRI%>%TIMESTAMP:::date-rfc3339% %HOSTNAME% %syslogtag:1:32% 
  %msg:::sp-if-no-1st-sp%%msg%")
```

You want to recalculate the `%PRI%` property. You cannot change the property but you can have your own local variables, eg `$.myprio` and use that. The result is:

```
template(name="myformat" type="string"
 string="<%$.myprio%>%TIMESTAMP:::date-rfc3339% %HOSTNAME% %syslogtag:1:32% %msg:::sp-if-no-1st-sp%%msg%")
if $programname == "myapplication-log" then {
    set $.myseverity = 6;
    if ($msg contains " DEBUG ") then set $.myseverity = 7;
    if ($msg contains " WARNING ") then set $.myseverity = 4;
    if ($msg contains " ERROR ") then set $.myseverity = 3;
    set $.myprio = 20*8+$.myseverity;
   *.* @192.168.1.4;myformat
}
```

---

For alternatives, look through the [rsyslog modules](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/modules/index.html) for input, parsing, message modification and output.  Possibilities are

1. input module `improg` that can run a program and accept input piped from it,
2. the parser `pmnormalize` using `liblognorm` which can parse data according to your rules, and
3. modification module `mmnormalize` using the same `liblognorm` which can modify the message.

The lognorm parser is probably the definitive solution, but is fairly complex and I cannot provide further advice in using it.

However, `improg`  is a simple way to externalize the pre-processing into a separate program written in any suitable language, or even a shell script, using inotify to *tail* the input file and munge the lines before passing them on to rsyslog.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This looks like it would work for me, but I was hoping to find a method of using conditionals 'within' the input module. Since the PRI can't be changed once the input has been parsed, the ideal location to determine the correct PRI would be during the input/parsing. That way the message is correct as parsed and all rules/tests later in the configuration would be followed without writing conditionals for 'in this case do what you normally would do, but use this different template.'

Comment: I've added some alternatives.

Comment: Looking at the rsyslog docs, `pmnormalize` looks interesting, and I think I agree that it would be proper way to handle this. I'll hunt down some examples of it's usage and see if I can work out something that works for my situation.

Comment: After looking at the pmnormalize docs, I've decided that your initial suggestion of using an output template will be much easier to implement. Thanks for the assist.